# Compare Azure Data WareHouse vs Azure Data Lake Analytics

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, parallel-data-warehouse

How do Azure Data warehouse & Azure Data Lake Compare in respective to
1) External Table 2) Internal Table 3) Column store Clustered Index 4) connecting to Internal & External Table from SQL Server Management Studio to Internal/External Tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to help.  Can you tell me more about the holistic thing you're trying to do here.  SQL DW and Azure Data Lake have their own scope and things they are best at.  Picking a narrow set of features without understanding your holistic goal could get us started in the wrong direction.
Guy

Comment: Typically both have external tables for ADW one can connect to it using connection string and query data in internal as well as external tables, how would one connect to Azure Data Lake Analytics external table or internal table via tools like SQL Management Studio and query the data on adhoc basis or do i have to push the process data into ADW/SQL DB for further access via such tools